# Sql error syntaxes with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database

Good day,

I have an issue using the phpmyadmin for my database, I'm in new in this and this is the mysql structure from previewmysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`attendant` 
  ( 
     `id`             INT NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `first_name`     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `names`          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
     `gender`         ENUM(0) NOT NULL, 
     `email`          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `phone`          INT(15) NULL, 
     `marital_status` ENUM(0) NOT NULL, 
     `added_date`     DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
     `membership`     ENUM(0) NOT NULL, 
     `address`        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `suburb`         ENUM(0) NOT NULL, 
     `partner_name`   VARCHAR(25) NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     UNIQUE `email_address` (`email`) 
  ) 
engine = innodb;
```

The error is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `phone` INT(15) NULL , `marital_sta' at line 1
```

And also attached is my phpmyadmin table structure.
[image]
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: What is "previewmysql"? It seems to be generating incorrect SQL for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENUM(0)` is wrong format , if you want that for gender roles then you can use :-

`ENUM('Male', 'Female')` i.e you can run this query :-

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`attendant` 
  ( 
     `id`             INT NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `first_name`     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `names`          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
     `gender`         ENUM('Male', 'Female') NOT NULL, 
     `email`          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `phone`          INT(15) NULL, 
     `marital_status` ENUM('Single','Married','divorced') NOT NULL, 
     `added_date`     DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
     `membership`     ENUM('no','yes') NOT NULL, 
     `address`        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `suburb`         ENUM('Cape Town','Woodstock') NOT NULL, 
     `partner_name`   VARCHAR(25) NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     UNIQUE `email_address` (`email`) 
  ) 
engine = innodb;
```

Comment: But that would be a very odd marital status

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply bringing some of the changes you have made now this is the error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0) NOT NULL , `email` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , `phone` INT(15) NULL , `marital_sta' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

> Try it.Hope errors goes boom.I just fixed your errors. But your table structure is not good enough. give time, then day by day you will also be expert on it.

```
  CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`attendant` 
  ( 
     `id`             INT NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `first_name`     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `names`          VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
     `gender`         ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL, 
     `email`          VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `phone`          INT(15),
     `marital_status` ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL, 
     `added_date`     DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
     `membership`     ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL, 
     `address`        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     `suburb`         ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL, 
     `partner_name`   VARCHAR(25) NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
     UNIQUE `email_address` (`email`) 
  ) 
engine = innodb;
```

Comment: hummm not sure what is wrong with my table structure, so I may be able to change it

Answer (score 2):

Modify ENUM declaration as ENUM ('male', 'female') for gender column and others also as shown in your table. It will not accept ENUM(0).

Answer (score 1):

You have used ENUM data type in your table. And provided 0 as argument but

> An enumeration value must be a quoted string literal

You can refer the mySql documentation for more information

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html